# How to make page scroll with background gif?

Tags: html, css

I've created a page with cool background gif, but when I change page's height (just by changing browser's window size), scroll doesn't appear and doesn't work.

Here is how I did it:

```
html body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.main {
  background-image: url("assets/video/background.gif");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I know, that I need to change `position` on something else, but that way my background just disappears. So, how can I do that?

This is how page looks 'normal':

[image]

And this is what happens, when I am trying to change window size:

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducable example so that we can help better.

Comment: In particular please make sure your gif is usable by us (ie uploaded somewhere communal).

Comment: Actually, this page is just for my front-end practice skills, I am not going to make this page public

Comment: You haven't shared all the code - in particular, we need to see your html! My first guess would be that there's no scrollbar because there's no content. A background image is just that - background. It's not content. If you want it treated as content, you need to place it as an image rather than background. (And your question about `position` looks to be a completely separate thing that you'll need to explain before we can understand your issue there.)